# Webview error API 19 below

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview in Android app. I show a map page in webview. 
When I show webview in API 23, It is correct view. But when I show API<19, It isn't correct view. I tried a lot of method but it is unsuccesfull. I have to do. You too can try. 
Build gradle api level : 14

API 23 : 
[image]

API 17 :
[image]

Activity Class :

```
public class KentRehberiActivity extends AbstractVatandasActivity{
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.kent_rehberi_layout);

    LinearLayout layKentRehberiKategoriList=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layKentRehberiKategoriList);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    layKentRehberiKategoriList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startWebView(SingletonClass.getAyarlar().getKentRehberiUrl());
}

private void startWebView(String url) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(KentRehberiActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Harita Getiriliyor...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you try to load another URL, like `https://google.com`? Maybe the problem is in the web app, not in Android client?

Comment: google works but my layout is not working

Comment: So the problem is in the URL you loading. What is it?